# how to get selected items when popup edit form in bootstrap 4 modal using jquery and laravel 6.x?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am working on laravel project which I need to use bootstrap modal for add and edit record. but I don't know how to get selected record to show in selection option dropdown.
Please take a look in my code below.

[image]

**Edit form**

[image]

**In select option should select one of the items that have been selected from the list but it doesn't**

[image]

**My Popup edit modal code**

```
<!--login form Modal -->
<div class="modal fade text-left" id="EditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel33" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel33">EDIT PROGRAM GRADE </h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <i class="bx bx-x"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form class="form" action="{{ route('grade.update') }}" method="POST">
                {{ method_field('patch') }}
                @csrf
                <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" name="grade_id" value="{{ $grade->id }}" id="gradeID">
                    <label>GRADE</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Grade Name" id="gradeName" name="grade_name" required>
                    </div>
                    <label>PROGRAM</label>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control" name="program_id" id="program" >
                            {{-- <option value="{{ $grade->Program->id }} selected " >{{ $grade->Program->name }}</option> --}}
                            @foreach ($selectProgram as $program)

                                <option value="{{ $program->id }} ">{{ $program->code }} - {{ $program->name }}</option>

                            @endforeach

                        </select>
                    </div>



                    <label>DISPLAY ORDER</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Display Order" id="displayOrder" name="display_order" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <i class="bx bx-x d-block d-sm-none"></i>
                        <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Close</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-1">
                        <i class="bx bx-check d-block d-sm-none"></i>
                        <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Update</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My Jquery script**

```
 <script>

$('#EditModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

  var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
  var grade = button.data('grade')
  var displayOrder = button.data('order')
  var program = button.data('program')
  var gradeID = button.data('id')

  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-body #gradeID').val(gradeID)
  modal.find('.modal-body #gradeName').val(grade)
  modal.find('.modal-body #displayOrder').val(displayOrder)
  modal.find('.modal-body #program').val(program)
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo should use if & else for showing this selected option if it's id match then selected otherwise not

```
<div class="form-group">
 <select class="form-control" name="program_id" id="program" >

 @foreach ($selectProgram as $program)
  @if($program->id==$grade->Program->id)//which variable for program id you passed from controller
 <option value="{{ $program->id }}" selected>{{ $program->code }} - {{ $program->name }} 
 </option>
@else
<option value="{{ $program->id }}">{{ $program->code }} - {{ $program->name }} 
 </option>
@endif

@endforeach

</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks albus_severus, This code worked if there is a variable pass from the edit controller to view but my code is "when I click on edit button it will popup edit modal which I use javascript to get value from view and populate to input form". I don't know who to get variable from javascript to compare in select option?

Answer (score 0):

Solution of umar_sharif, will work,but you have to put your modal <div class="modal fade text-left" id="EditModal"... inside of foreach loop when loading your data, but you have to give a different id, to achieve that you can concatenate in a variable for example "EditModal-" + program or any id that you can use to make modal with differents ids. Theses ids should be the same to fire up modals. So in this way you are creating so many modals as data items you have.